# Custom collectionView implementation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

I am trying to implement a CollectionView as in the picture below. As you can see, if an element is selected, it has a corresponding check mark in the upper right corner

[image]

First I tried to find the AbstractLayout category ID in the SelectionChanged event, and already inside it I was looking for an element named = "showIfSelected", but when searching inside collectionView I always got null. I have read several articles about why this is the case, but I have not found a solution to the problem. Maybe someone can tell me how to achieve the result I need in the end?

.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Paraglider.MobileApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Paraglider.MobileApp.Models"
    x:DataType="viewmodels:CatalogPageViewModel"
    x:Class="Paraglider.MobileApp.Pages.CatalogPage">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="#FFFEF6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        ...

        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="20, 0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

            <CollectionView
                x:Name="collectionView"
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">

                <CollectionView.Header>...</CollectionView.Header>

                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{OnIdiom Default=2}" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Category">
                        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="{Binding Id}">
                            
                            <Image 
                                Aspect="AspectFit" 
                                WidthRequest="165" 
                                Source="pzv.svg" 
                                Margin="0, 10" />
                            
                            <Image
                                x:Name="showIfSelected"
                                Aspect="AspectFit" 
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="130, 0, autoSize, autoSize"  
                                Source="selected_category.svg" 
                                IsVisible="True" >
                                <Image.Shadow>
                                    <Shadow Brush="Black" Offset="0, 10" Opacity="0.1" Radius="15" />
                                </Image.Shadow>
                            </Image>
                            
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            </CollectionView>

        </ScrollView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class CatalogPage : ContentPage
{
    public CatalogPage(CatalogPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var prev = e.PreviousSelection.Select(x => (Category)x).ToList();
        var current = e.CurrentSelection.Select(x => (Category)x).ToList();

        var unselected = prev.ExceptBy(current.Select(x => x.Id), x => x.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var item in unselected)
        {
            var layout = this.FindByName<AbsoluteLayout>($"{item.Id}");
            var image = layout.FindByName<Image>("showIfSelected");
            image.IsVisible = false;
        }

        var selected = current.ExceptBy(prev.Select(x => x.Id), x => x.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var item in selected)
        {
            var layout = this.FindByName<AbsoluteLayout>($"{item.Id}");
            var image = layout.FindByName<Image>("showIfSelected");
            image.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to **bind** IsVisible to a property of your model

Comment: @jason but I will have 15-20 categories in the list. Do I need to create a separate field for each category? And what if, in theory, I may not know the number of categories?

Comment: Why would that matter?  Just add a Selected bool to each Category

Comment: @jason Okay, I got it, thanks. I think that will work for me.

Comment: Come on guys, the creators of MAUI are giving you great tools for writing rules for UI styling, so you don't have to write C# code for everything on your own. This is textbook example for Selected VisualState. The least you can do is give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jason, you can directly bind `IsVisible` to a property of your **Model** like below:

**XAML:**

```
 <Image
     Aspect="AspectFit"          
     Source="selected_category.png" 
     IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                  
 </Image>
```

**Model:**

```
public partial class Category : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isSelected;
}
```

Comment: No. Please no. Making Model with properties for something that has VisualState. More importantly - built in visual state that you just have to use. And referencing images with .svg will not wok on IOS. You should refer to them as PNG, despite the fact they are included as SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

Combine styling:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0

And visual states:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-7.0

You can use the VisualStates, to determine what style to be used.
CollectionView has a VisualState Selected.

You can name your visual element, lets say that picture, and use styling to change properties of exactly that visual element.

No need of this wall of text, everything can be done in the XAML, with zero code behind it.

Edit: Other users suggested, you may need example how to do it.
Here is a working code, from one of my test projects (on MAUI NET 7.0)

```
<Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke".../>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" ..."/>
                        <Setter TargetName="line1"
                            Property="Label.TextColor"
                            Value="Black" />...
```

The important part you can notice, is that I have a Label VisualElement, that has the Name "line1", and I access the property TextColor, and apply the value Black, when the item gets selected.

This throws terrible runtime exceptions, if you apply this style, and fail to provide child VisualElement of type Label, and the specified Name.

On the plus side, the alternative to this is more time consuming (in magnitudes) and also prone to errors.